# (ODR-use question) priority_queue of identically named structs in different files

Tags: c++, g++, one-definition-rule

Consider the following files:

`a.cpp`:

```
#include <queue>

struct Event {  
    int a;
};

static bool operator<(const Event &a, const Event &b) {
    return a.a < b.a;
}

void external_insert(std::priority_queue<Event> &pqu, Event event) {
    pqu.push(event);
}

int main() {
    // fails
    std::priority_queue<Event> pqu;
    external_insert(pqu, Event());

    // works
    // std::priority_queue<Event> pqu;
    // pqu.push(Event());
    return 0;
}
```

`b.cpp`:

```
#include <queue>

struct Event {
    int a, b;
};

static bool operator<(const Event &a, const Event &b) {
    return a.a < b.a;
}

void some_unused_function() {
    std::priority_queue<Event> evqu;
    evqu.push(Event());
}
```

Then compile these two files to two executables using:

```
g++ a.cpp b.cpp -o ab
g++ b.cpp a.cpp -o ba
```

And then run both under valgrind:

```
valgrind ./ab
# ... ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts ...
valgrind ./ba
# ... ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts ...
```

The exact output from valgrind for the two programs can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tomsmeding/ff4e77f181ff6d87c5bcf03531701435).

No errors occur when doing either of the following things:

- Replacing "Event" with any other name in one of the two files
- Making both structs the same size
- Choosing the second set of two lines in `main()` instead of the first
- Replacing the use of `priority_queue` with `vector`, and using `push_back` instead of `push`

I'm inclined to believe this is an issue in the compiler (compiler bug?) where the naming for the template-instantated methods for the two versions of `priority_queue` conflict with each other.

Is this a known issue, is this a new bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please before asking such questions compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`.

Comment: @YSC I agree, and I had (well, without the Werror). However, doing so generates no output. Only enabling LTO, as Florian Weimer suggested, produces warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have violated the One Definition Rule, so your program has undefined behavior.

To fix it,  you can put one or both structs into a namespace to make them unique.  If they are not needed outside their own .cpp files, you can put them each into an anonymous namespace.

Comment: Yes, that's it. In the [standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) paragraph 6.2.6, it is indeed stated that different types need to have different names, even if they are in different translation units. I never realised this was a problem, and thought translation units provided namespace-like separation. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

As [John Zwinck said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52627202/8316315), this is an ODR violation.  You can use `-flto` to diagnose such violations:

```
$ g++ -O2 -flto a.cpp b.cpp 
a.cpp:3:8: warning: type 'struct Event' violates the C++ One Definition Rule [-Wodr]
 struct Event {
        ^
b.cpp:3:8: note: a different type is defined in another translation unit
 struct Event {
        ^
b.cpp:4:12: note: the first difference of corresponding definitions is field 'b'
     int a, b;
            ^
b.cpp:3:8: note: a type with different number of fields is defined in another translation unit
 struct Event {
        ^
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about LTO but not that it can diagnose things like this very well.